# How to organise different dropdowns in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, filepond

I use VUE for my project and i really don't know how to deal with different dropdowns.
For example, I've got 3 different dropdowns and I need to display them by **adding active css class**, no problems here. But how to manage their visibility and change it for each dropdown separately, because only one dropdown can be seen at the same time? I've tried to do it with slots but it didn't halp me. Is somebody could help me?
My code:

```
     <div class="account-settings-quickview">
        <span class="icon-settings">
          <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
          <!-- SVG ARROW -->
          <svg class="svg-arrow">
          <use xlink:href="#svg-arrow"></use>
          </svg>
          <!-- /SVG ARROW -->
        </span>

        <!-- PIN -->
        <span class="pin soft-edged primary">49</span>
        <!-- /PIN -->

        <!-- DROPDOWN NOTIFICATIONS -->
        <ul class="dropdown notifications no-hover">
       
        </ul>
        <!-- /DROPDOWN NOTIFICATIONS -->
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-if` directive:

Add `v-if` to your component and some condition that would switch dropdowns based on what you need to show at the moment. Like these:

```
<dropdown1 v-if="somecondition=='A'"></dropdown>
<dropdown2 v-else-if="somecondition=='B'"></dropdown>
<dropdown3 v-else></dropdown>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know this method. But  would like to know if there is another way to make it cleaner.

Comment: I believe you can use v-show="condition". You can also create a component of your three dropdowns and pass condition via a prop. So in your main view you just use the component but in the component view you have this v-if logic. That would make code a little bit cleaner.